# How to use vlookup or lookup or any variants of lookup to deposit an array of strings to another table?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

[image]

Hello. How to use vlookup/lookup/any other types of lookup to find students whose score matches the criteria of the column in the second table (ie. score=1,score=2 etc) and then write the names of the student into the rows of the table?

I have tried the standard lookup formula but it only returns one name

In the picture, the formula should be put in the green cells where I expect to see the following values in the second table.

Edit: I get Divide 0 error when I applied the formula suggested by @FlexYourData

[image]

As shown in the sheet above, I want to deposit names into cell C81. With the condition that the names to be depositted into cell C81 should be the name of the students who get Band 1 for sem 1, based on another Excel sheet. (see the 3rd photo)

[image]
Above is the sheet of name "Keseluruhan". I want to deposit names from B15:B50 into the sheet in the previous screenshot in the cell C81 if the students has a "Tp Keseluruhan" (Sheet "Keseluruhan": P15:P50) of "1".

Note that, the cell P15:P50 in sheet "Keseluruhan" does not contain direct integer values. Rather, it contains formula:
[image]

Comment: do you have TEXTJOIN and FILTER functions in your version of Excel?

Answer (score 0):

It'll be easier if you have the score value in a row of its own.

You can use this formula to get the count of students per score value:

```
=COUNTIF($B$3:$B$10,D$2)
```

This formula will get the names for each score and comma-separate them:

```
=TEXTJOIN(",",TRUE,FILTER($A$3:$A$10,$B$3:$B$10=D$2))
```

Or if you prefer to return each name in a separate row:

```
=FILTER($A$3:$A$10,$B$3:$B$10=D$2)
```

[image]

Comment: Hello. I get a #DIV/0! error because most of my cells are waiting for input. What amendments should I do?

Comment: What formula is causing the error? Please edit your post and add a new screenshot showing the error and the formula causing the error. You can use the =FORMULATEXT( function to display the formula in the spreadsheet.

Comment: I've added the additional screenshot to the edit. :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this formula:

```
=TEXTJOIN(",",1,IF($B$2:$B$9=NUMBERVALUE((RIGHT(F1,LEN(F1)-FIND("=",F1)))),$A$2:$A$9,""))
```

[image]